# what if I want add a empty row between different name in the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with the structure like:

table1

```
name      date      company
Alice   19-01-01    A Global
Alice   19-03-01    C Global
Alice   19-03-01    C Global
Bob     19-01-01    B Corp
Alice   19-03-01    C Global
Bob     19-01-01    D Corp
Peter   19-02-01    E Subject
Peter   20-04-11    J Subject
```

what should I do if I want add a empty row bewteen names to separate each other in html

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table1 order by name, date ASC";
$queryRecord = $conn->query($sql);

<?php foreach($queryRecord as $res) :?>
<table><tr><td>
<?php echo $res['name'];?>
</td><td>
<?php echo $res['date'];?>
<td>
<?php echo $res['company'];?>
</td></tr><?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: you can add empty tr in for loop or if you want you can also add padding css to get space between each records.

Comment: thanks, but if I add a empty tr then the tr will appear after every single row right? what I want is let said it will show all row of Alice and genrate a empty row and show bob and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the name from the previous row. Whenever the name in the current row is different, add a blank row to the table.

```
<table>
<?php 
$last_name = null;
foreach($queryRecord as $res) :
if ($last_name && $last_name != $res['gp_name']):?>
<tr></tr><?php endif;
$last_name = $res['gp_name'];
?>
<tr><td>
<?php echo $res['gp_name'];?>
</td><td>
<?php echo $res['date'];?>
<td>
<?php echo $res['company'];?>
</td></tr><?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, this code is nearly achieve my need, but the last row doesn't add the empty row. is there any method  which can add a empty row in the end of every item?

Comment: If you always want a blank row at the end, just add it before `</table>`.